# add data to ListView in a class which extends Activity and not ListActivity

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a Listview in a relative layout. How can I add data to ListView from the ManActivity which extends Activity. I could have used adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() if i have used the class which extends ListActivity.... i guess. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

```
Message msg[] = new Message[]
                {
                    new Message(1, "Hello World", "Thank You"), new Message(1, "Hello World 2", "Thank You 2")
                };
adapter = new MyAdapter(context, R.layout.row, msg);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adding this will make my app Crash

```
adapter.add(new Message(1, "Hello World3", "Thank You3"));
```

**Logcat text**

```
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:179)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at com.abhishek.ally2.chat.doInBackground(chat.java:28)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at com.abhishek.ally2.chat.doInBackground(chat.java:1)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-07 20:22:53.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     ... 4 more
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
package com.abhishek.ally2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message>{
    private final Context context;
    private final Message data[];
    int layoutResourceId;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Message[] values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, layoutResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = values;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        MessageHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflator.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new MessageHolder();
            holder.pic = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.pic);
            holder.msg = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.msg);
            holder.time = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.time);
            row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (MessageHolder)row.getTag();
        }
            Message message = data[position];
            holder.msg.setText(message.msg);
            holder.time.setText(message.time);

        return row;

    }


    static class MessageHolder {
        ImageView pic;
        TextView msg;
        TextView time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether you use an adapter or not has nothing to do with whether you extend ListActivity or not.  `myListView.setAdapter(adapter)`.  So what *is* your question?

Comment: i have already used this... now i want to add more data... Something like myListView.addToExistingData()... getting what i want to say ? :P

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but you could take a look at the [source code of class ListActivity](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java) and try to mimic some or all of its behavior.

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion.  You add data to the adapter, or rather to the data source it is bound to, *not* the ListView.  the ListView is simply responsible for whatever views the adapter presents to it, which the adapter builds from the dataset it is bound to.

Comment: @Simon i added some code. Please have a look...

Comment: Grrrrr.  Your problem has nothing to do with your question.  What exception do you get?  Post the logcat stack trace please.  Your question has nothing to do with "how do I add data".  It's "please help me to find the bug in my code".  Also show the `add` method of your adapter.

Comment: @Simon Sorry... I am a newbie in Android.... Can you point me where I am wrong

Comment: Please post the code for your adapter

Comment: OK, you're not overriding `add`.  You need to read some tutorials.  Here's one to start.  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html  The key point to understand is that you do not add data to the ListView, or to the adapter, you add it to the ***dataset***

Answer (score 0):

To add data to your listview you need to add data to your dataset and then tell adapter dataset changed by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` as you mentioned. So to have list working you need dataset (i.e. Array) listview (in layout) and adapter that binds these two togeter (i.e. `ArrayAdapter`). You also need to tell list where is its adapter by calling `list.setAdapter()`. `ListActivity` is just a helper class, not a requirement and ListView works perfectly fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

alternativly to the marcins answer, you can manage your data via the adapter you already set, by adding/removing the data directly to/from the  adapter with `adapter.add(item)` etc. the underlying list you used to create your adapter (if you used one) will be updated to and you don't need to worry about notifies. `notifyDataSetChanged()` makes more sense, if you add any observers to your adapter.

**Edit:**

i m not able to comment your post and you edited your examplecode afterwards. since you try to update your list from an AsyncTask (as far as i see from stacktrace), you have to call `runOnUiThread(Runnable r)`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.add(new Message(1, "Hello World3", "Thank You3"));
    }
});
```

**Edit2:**

you don't need to have a member for your values inside your adapter, since these values are already member of the extended arrayadapter. to access one specific message in your `getView` you can call `getItem(position)`. that way you don't need to overwrite your the `listAdapter.add(T item)`

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```
Years years = readYearsList(); // return the Years array.

ListView listYears = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
YearAdapter yearAdapter = new YearAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.rowyears, years); // YearAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Years>
listYears.setAdapter(yearAdapter);
```